# Powershell add an item to an xml array property

Tags: .net, xml, powershell

i have a problem adding values to an xml array property.
The xml looks like this:

```
$xml = [xml]@"
<letters>
    <letter><to>mail a</to></letter>
    <letter>
        <to>mail a</to>
        <to>mail b</to>
    </letter>
</letters>
"@

$letter = $xml.letters.letter[1]
$letter.to
#mail a
#mail b
```

now i want to add items ("mail c", "mail d") to the "to" array:

```
$letter.to
#mail a
#mail b
#mail c
#mail d
```

But i don't seem to be able to.

a) simply trying to set anything to the property results in a misleading error:

```
$letter.to += "a"
#"to" kann nicht festgelegt werden, da nur Zeichenfolgen als Werte zum Festlegen von XmlNode-Eigenschaften verwendet werden können.
#Bei Zeile:1 Zeichen:9
#+ $letter. <<<< to += "a"
#    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
#    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
```

But that probably boils down to "to" not having a setter:

```
$letter | Get-Member
#Name       MemberType      Definition
#[bunch of stuff]
#to         Property        System.Object[] {get;}
```

b) Setting a value via SetAttribute partly works, but results in unusable (and very strange) behaviour:

```
$letter.SetAttribute("to", "mail c")
$letter.to
#mail c     <- why is it up front?
#mail a
#mail b

$letter.SetAttribute("to", "mail d")
$letter.to
#mail d     <- why is mail c gone?
#mail a
#mail b
```

Does anyone have an Idea what to try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick, you can create a fragment and add the innerxml for the to tag (since it's unstructured):

```
$letter = $xml.letters.letter[1]
$to= $xml.CreateDocumentFragment();
# Create the to node
$to.InnerXml = "<to>mail c</to>"
$letter.AppendChild($to);
# show the node
$letter
```

Altarnatively you could create the to tag on the document with the following:

```
$to = $xml.CreateElement("to")
```

Then set it's property (inner text) :

```
$to.InnerText = "mail c"
```

And append the item with

```
$letter.AppendChild($to)
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want to create a new `XmlElement`, set the `InnerText` value, and append it to the parent `<letter>` element :

```
$to = $xml.CreateElement("to")
$to.InnerText = "mail c"
$letter.AppendChild($to)
$letter.to
```

Output :

```
mail a
mail b
mail c
```

Similar example can be found in the MSDN documentation of [`XmlNode.AppendChild()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.appendchild%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).